# Flutter Firestore listen on Stream

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using this code to listen on document changes:

```
Stream stream = db.doc(docRef.path).snapshots();
```

But I can't find a way to unsubscribe this listener from Firebase. I checked the [Stream](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.0/dart-async/Stream-class.html) class. Is this happening by default if I close the app? I found examples for this in other languages [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web_5) but I can't figure out how to do this in dart.

Any advice? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't unsubscribe from `Stream`. You unsubscribe from [StreamSubscription](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html) using the `cancel()` method.

So first start listening to your stream using `.listen()` on the stream, this will return you `StreamSubscription` which you can then cancel.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if `cancel()` is automatically called when the app is closed?

Comment: It should, I think. But even if it does not, Firebase will automatically remove the subscription after some time.